# What does it do this assembly code?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm new to assembly language and I would like to know what the code below does:

```
Address   Hex dump          Command                                                        
01356A60  /$  53            PUSH EBX                                                            
01356A61  |.  8BD9          MOV EBX,ECX
01356A63  |.  8B43 04       MOV EAX,DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+4]
01356A66  |.  56            PUSH ESI
01356A67  |.  8B70 10       MOV ESI,DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+10]
01356A6A  |.  85F6          TEST ESI,ESI
01356A6C  |.- 74 5B         JZ SHORT 01356AC9
01356A6E  |.  8BC6          MOV EAX,ESI
01356A70  |.  8D50 01       LEA EDX,[EAX+1]
01356A73  |>  8A08          /MOV CL,BYTE PTR DS:[EAX]
01356A75  |.  40            |INC EAX
01356A76  |.  84C9          |TEST CL,CL
01356A78  |.- 75 F9         \JNZ SHORT 01356A73
01356A7A  |.  2BC2          SUB EAX,EDX
01356A7C  |.  57            PUSH EDI
01356A7D  |.  8BF8          MOV EDI,EAX
01356A7F  |.- 74 47         JZ SHORT 01356AC8
```

What I can understand is running this part of code is that at `EAX` there is for example "abcdefg" and at the `EDX` there is "bcdefg" (the same string without the first letter), and that during the loop, `EAX` is incremented eating a single letter each time...but for example `MOV CL,BYTE PTR DS:[EAX]`, what is its goal? Is there some pattern code in those lines that a newbie like me can't see?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pattern, and it's called "assembler". If you need to ask for help on *individual* instructions, then you are not ready to take on full functions.

> MOV CL,BYTE PTR DS:[EAX]", what is its goal?

The goal is to load the byte on the address stored in `ds:[eax]` into the 8-bit register `cl`.

Typically, single instructions don't have a 'goal'. The larger context suggests the loop is to find the end of a zero-terminated string. As you can (hopefully) see, the found "end" of the string in `eax` is then subtracted by `edx` -- the string start -- and subtracting a pointer to the end of a string by the start results in the string *length*. After that, the example peters out in (probably) a set-up routine for further processing.